# is there any event page changed (angular2)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Is there any event of page changing?
What I need: if somebody change page need to do something, but not if he change page for page /terms (for example).

Comment: What is "page changing"?

Comment: You probably want the [@CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html) route lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html). Implementing functions:

```
onDestroy() // navigating from component
onInit() // opening component
```